# Why is my WP site broken in Firefox?

Tags: wordpress, firefox, zurb-foundation

I am building a WordPress site for a client and currently the site is broken on Firefox. Everything shows up, but on the initial landing, only the header is visible and then you must scroll one page width to see the rest of the site. I was able to fix this by changing the position of the header within the PHP file but this breaks the mobile functionality and the header on Chrome. Please help.

The link is live so you can view the problem at hogarcotui.org and here is the HTML and PHP header file

```html
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
  <?php do_action( 'foundationPress_after_body'); ?>



  <div class="small-12 xlarge-12 columns">
    <div class="medium-2 large-2 xlarge-2 columns show-for-medium-up">
      <a href="http://www.en.hogarcotui.org">
        <img class="logo" src="../wp-content/uploads/2015/01/logo.png">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="small-3 columns show-for-small-only invisible">...</div>
    <div class="small-6 columns end show-for-small-only">
      <a href="http://www.en.hogarcotui.org">
        <img class="logo" src="../wp-content/uploads/2015/01/logo.png">
      </a>
    </div>


    <div class="medium-8 large-9 xlarge-9 columns show-for-medium-up">
      <h1 class="name">Hogar de Ancianos en Cotuí RD</h1>

    </div>
    <div class="small-2 small-offset-6 medium-2 medium-offset-8 large-2 large-offset-10 xlarge-2 xlarge-offset-10 columns language">
      <a href="http://www.hogarcotui.org" id="langLink">Spanish</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="off-canvas-wrap" data-offcanvas>
    <div class="inner-wrap">

      <?php do_action( 'foundationPress_layout_start'); ?>



      <nav class="tab-bar show-for-small-only">
        <section class="left-small">
          <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon" href="#"><span></span></a>
        </section>
        <section class="middle tab-bar-section">

          <h1>Hogar Cotui RD</h1>

        </section>
      </nav>

      <?php get_template_part( 'parts/off-canvas-menu'); ?>

      <?php get_template_part( 'parts/top-bar'); ?>

      <section class="container" role="document">
        <?php do_action( 'foundationPress_after_header'); ?>
```

Comment: Are you using an off-canvas navigation? Foundation has an issue with this sometimes, however, it's normally in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Check the source code you have inserted the header twice. You see twice this:

```
<html class="no-js" lang="en-US" >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.hogarcotui.org/wp-content/themes/FoundationPress/css/foundation.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.hogarcotui.org/wp-content/themes/FoundationPress/css/style.css" />
```

You have to correct the html structure. I need header, page and footer code to fully understand what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No double header here...
I would suggest the following changes in your stylesheet.

1. remove `overflow:hidden` from `.off-canvas-wrap`.
   This will position the content below the header.
2. add `float:left` to `.top-bar-container, .tab-bar`.
   This will set the menu background right.
3. add `overflow-x:hidden` to `body`. 
   This will remove the horizontal scroll.

GL!